# Unanswered page loses special appearance of tags on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tags, tags

[Unanswered Tags http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/2120/unanswered.tif](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/2120/unanswered.tif)
See `feature-request`, `discussion`, and others? They don't have their special appearance.
This is on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because they don't have the CSS class applied.

At first it's like:

```
class="post-tag moderator-tag" 
class="post-tag required-tag"
```

But then it's like:

```
class="post-tag"
```

Comment: What's that meme?

Comment: Rape face?

Comment: Actually, I think I am a bit ashamed for even participating in your shenanigans.

Comment: Oh so that's where it is. Only heard the extracted version and didn't think of the meme name.